# Remote logging into a website and fetching HTML source with WPFs WebBrowser class

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to write a application which logs the user on a specific website after he inputs his account information and then present an specific site in the window which is only accessible after login.

I'm trying to do this with the WebBrowser Class from `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`
However, even after searching other examples I can't seem to get past the login.
I used `HttpFox` to analyze the `GET` and `POST` data and found out that Cookies Sent are: `_utma/b/c/z, clientid, csrftoken and sessionid` and received `sessionid`.

Ok now I know that the _utma cookies are something about google analytics so I think I can ignore them? The csrftoken seems to have the same value always.

Can anyone give me some hints how to make the `POST` request in c# with the webbrowser class?
Help is very much appreciated, thanks! :)

update1: I already know the general methods I have to use but I'm having problems with the actual implementation. What should I include in the post request and how to get and save the sessionId,... things like that. I couldn't find any working example where someone is logging into some 3rd party website with the help of the WebBrowser class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebClient.UploadData method to post data and to receive response from your script

Comment: Thanks but I already know the general methods I have to use but I'm having problems with the actual implementation. What I should include in the post request and how to get and save the sessionId,... things like that. I couldn't find any working example where someone is logging into some 3rd party website with the help of the WebBrowser class.